# The Wikipedia example of a Statistical model and its PDF

Tags: modeling, density-function, model

The [example section of Wikipedia's article on Statistical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model#An_example) says:

> Suppose that we have a population of children, with the ages of the children distributed uniformly, in the population. The height of a child will be stochastically related to the age: e.g. when we know that a child is of age 7, this influences the chance of the child being 1.5 meters tall. We could formalize that relationship in a linear regression model, like this: $\text{height}_i = b_0 + b_1 \text{age}_i + \epsilon_i$, where $b_0$ is the intercept, $b_1$ is a parameter that age is multiplied by to obtain a prediction of height, $\epsilon_i$ is the error term, and $i$ identifies the child. This implies that height is predicted by age, with some error.
>
> To do statistical inference, we would first need to assume some probability distributions for the $\epsilon_i$. For instance, we might assume that the $\epsilon_i$ distributions are i.i.d. **Gaussian, with zero mean**. In this instance, the model would have 3 parameters: $b_0$, $b_1$, and the variance of the Gaussian distribution.

It sounds like this model assumes that each point on the line $y = b_0 + b_1x$ represents the mean height of children of age specified by the $x$ coordinate of the point. For example: the point $[2.4; 0.85]$ laying on the line means that the mean height of children of age 2.4 years is 0.85 meters.

Furthermore, it sounds like the model assumes that the variance $\sigma^2$ of height is exactly the same for all the different height categories (so it does not change with the age of the children, which is fine for the purpose of this simplified example).

I picture the statistical model as follows: for each point on the line, there is a vertical 1D Gaussian (parallel to the $Y$ axis) with variance $\sigma^2$. Therefore there is infinitely many of those vertical 1D Gaussians (with the same $\sigma^2$) along the line, one Gaussian for each point on the line.

I guess all the 1D Gaussians combined are the part that defines the PDF of this statistical model as a whole. However, **I am not sure if I understand how to normalize the PDF of the model so the probability densities in the 2D space near the whole line add up to 1.** Since the integral of every PDF needs to be normalized to add up to 1, it seems like we cannot use the normalization factor $1 / (\sigma \sqrt {2\pi})$ of the 1D Gaussian, but instead we need to compensate for the infinite amount of 1D Gaussians along the line.

This is how I would solve the problem: I would define the sample space $\mathcal{S}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$, so $\mathcal{S} = \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, x_{\text{min}} < x < x_{\text{max}} \,\,\wedge\,\, y_{\text{min}} < y < y_{\text{max}} \right\}$ would be the domain of the function $f(x,y)$ representing the PDF of the model (1D Gaussians placed on the line, with the line not being infinite, but confined to a finite patch on $\mathbb R^2$). This would ensure that $f(x,y)$ is not defined over an infinitely large area, so that the integral of $f(x,y)$ isn't infinite and the PDF can be properly normalized:

$$
f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\gamma}
\text{exp}\left(
  -0.5 \left( \frac{y-(b_0 + b_1 x)}{\sigma} \right)^2
\right)
$$

Where $\gamma = \iint_\mathcal{S} \gamma f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$ (the volume under all the Gaussians).

However, using a finite-sized domain for the PDF seems ugly and not something what a statistician would do. After all, the value of 1D Gaussian function is defined over the whole $\mathbb R^2$, without the need to artifically "cut it off" by defining it over a limited domain.

**What is the correct way of defining PDF for the Wikipedia example?** How would it look like (assuming the model has 3 parameters $b_0, b_1, \sigma^2$ as mentioned above)?

Comment: Your comments reflect a good understanding of what otherwise is a relatively poor account of a regression model.  In most applications interest focuses on the conditional distributions and there is no need to obtain a full joint distribution (which often is not even relevant).  Even when you have some use for the full distribution, often you don't even need to normalize it: you just need to know probabilities relative to some other distribution(s). But if you want to normalize it, do so in the standard way: integrate the density. There's no need to limit the second coordinate of $\mathcal S.$

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment. To lower my confusion: by "conditional distribution", did you mean the distribution of height for children of a specific age (so a single 1D Gaussian)? Wouldn't the result of integrating the (joint?) density $f(x,y)$ be infinity if $\mathcal{S}$ is the whole $\mathbb R^2$? So my suggested approach of using a "finite-sized" $\mathcal{S}$ would be the correct way to normalize $f(x,y)$? By the way, that's a great point about normalizing relative to different distributions, thanks for sharing your insight!

Comment: The result will not be infinite, because the integral of each conditional distribution is unity (axiomatically).  Because the density of age is a constant (you are told the distribution is "uniform"), the Normalizing constant for the joint distribution is simply to divide by the range of ages.